# How to use JAXBElement<String> in Web Service?

Tags: java, xml, wcf, web-services

I am developing an interoperable web service using WCF which I am consuming from a Java client.  When I created the proxy class it generated all the getter and setter methods as well as a `JAXBElement<String>` field.  I searched for this in the JDK API and found the constructor:

```
JAXBElement(QName name, Class<T> declaredType, Class scope, T value)
```

How should I use this constructor?  Please explain the parameters and let me know if there is a good tutorial on the Internet describing its use.

Comment: Have you read the Javadoc? http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXBElement.html#JAXBElement%28javax.xml.namespace.QName,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Class,%20T%29

Comment: Not an answer but the java developers will thank you if your WCF DataMembers have IsRequired=true (not possible always but in most cases should be acceptable). Then you wouln't get the JAXBEelement. Also consider using setting the Order explicitly.

Answer (score 28):

A solution this problem is, you do not need to create a seperate constructor for creating a `JAXBElement`. The respected element can be retrieved from `objectFactory.create........()` method. Suppose you want to create and set some value in response object, and argument is as of `JAXBElement` type, then you need to do this way:

```
someResponseObj.setMyValue(objectFactory.create.......()); 
/*method name that will be return a JAXBElement in setter()*/
```

**Note:** Please check the `ObjectFactory` reference because there can be multiple `ObjectFactory` classes in generated code so you need to refer the exact one which is associated to the class of that package.

Answer (score 16):

I'm just doing the exact same thing, using a Java Client to comsume WCF web service. I'm using the jaxws maven plugin to generate the client side code.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <packageName>com.package1</packageName>
        <sourceDestDir>src/main/java</sourceDestDir>
        <wsdlDirectory>src/main/resources</wsdlDirectory>
        <wsdlFiles>
            <wsdlFile>wcf_webservice.wsdl</wsdlFile>
        </wsdlFiles>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

You should have an ObjectFactory class in your `com.package1` which you can use to create your JAXBElements for you eg:

```
ObjectFactory factory = new ObjectFactory();
MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
JAXBElement<MyObject> elem = factory.createMyObject(myObject);
```

Just as a side note, you'll need to flatten the wcf wsdl before jaxws can use it.

Answer (score 13):

Just in case someone ends up here looking for a solution: Instead of using JAXBElement one can use only the Type by setting the generateElementProperty to false in a bindings file.

In my case Im using maven to generate the stub files from wsdl.

partial pom file and bindings file (in this config is called javabindings.xml)

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.9</version>
        <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
            <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/wsdl2java/generated-sources/src/main/java</sourceRoot>
            <wsdlOptions>
                <wsdlOption>
                    <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/yourWsdlFileOrURL.wsdl</wsdl>

                    <extraargs>
                        <extraarg>-verbose</extraarg>
                        <extraarg>-b</extraarg>
                        <extraarg>${basedir}/src/main/resources/javabindings.xml</extraarg>
                    </extraargs>                        
                </wsdlOption>
            </wsdlOptions>

            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

```
<jaxb:bindings version="2.0" 
xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" 
xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc" 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"> 
<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="http://localhost:15002/MiddlewareDataServiceConversion?xsd=xsd0"> 
    <jaxb:bindings node="/xs:schema"> 
        <jaxb:globalBindings generateElementProperty="false"/> 
    </jaxb:bindings> 
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Answer (score 5):

I stumbled upon this question while I was looking for the same answer. I posted an answer but found a few problems. Here is a way to do it:

```
new javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement(
        new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://locationOfURI", "nameOfElement"),
        javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement.class, 
        null, what your object's value is );
```

The last means the type parameter of `JAXBElement`.

Hope this works.

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter **name** is a qualified name (local name + name space) of the XML element you are mirroring.

**declaredType** is class object of the class you are binding your XML element to.

**scope** is usage scope of the XML Element, but you can set it to null.

**value** is an instance of **declaredType** class i.e. the actual Java object bound to actual XML element instance.

Answer (score 0):

So where is the usage.. and example. I want it..

I found it. So you maybe do that..
It will work.

```
Text t = new Text();
t.setValue("I need limo transportation");
JAXBElement<Text> text = new JAXBElement(SERVICE, Text.class, t);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use minOccurs="1" instead of minOccurs="0" in your wsdl. For some (good) reason, the code generator needs this info in order to convert parameters to basic java type parameters.

Comment: Well it worked for me because I had minOccurs="0" but if you already have that... I dunno.

Answer (score 0):

I had problems trying the above methods using JAXBElement as per the documentation and I found this instead, which worked perfectly for me.

```
        import javax.xml.bind.*;

        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(YOURCLASS.class);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(yourInstantiatedClass,  System.out);
```