# parameter JAXBElement String

Tags: java, jaxb, annotations

I' have simple question about JAXB. Here is the sample code:

```
   //setter that has input JAXBElement
   b.setBIC(JAXBElement<String> value);
```

How can I initialize the input element, that uses String from other object?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use JAXBElement<String> in Web Service?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393920/how-to-use-jaxbelementstring-in-web-service)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can create an instance of `JAXBElement` directly or if you generated your Java model from an XML schema use a convience method on the generated `ObjectFactory` class.

```
package org.example.schema;

import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("org.example.schema");

        Root root = new Root();

        QName fooQName = new QName("http://www.example.org/schema", "foo");
        JAXBElement<String> fooValue = new JAXBElement<String>(fooQName, String.class, "FOO");
        root.setFoo(fooValue);

        ObjectFactory objectFactory = new ObjectFactory();
        JAXBElement<String> barValue = objectFactory.createRootBar("BAR");
        root.setBar(barValue);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);
    }

}
```

**schema.xsd**

The above demo code is based on a Java model generated from the following XML schema.  The reason you get a `JAXBElement<String>` property in the first place is when you have an element that is both `nillable="true"` and `minOccurs="0"`.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/schema" 
    xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/schema" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <element name="root">
        <complexType>
            <sequence>
                <element name="foo" type="string" minOccurs="0" nillable="true"/>
                <element name="bar" type="string" minOccurs="0" nillable="true"/>
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
    </element>
</schema>
```

**Root**

The following class was generated from `schema.xsd` and contains properties like the one in your question.

```
package org.example.schema;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {"foo","bar"})
@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
public class Root {

    @XmlElementRef(name = "foo", namespace = "http://www.example.org/schema", type = JAXBElement.class)
    protected JAXBElement<String> foo;
    @XmlElementRef(name = "bar", namespace = "http://www.example.org/schema", type = JAXBElement.class)
    protected JAXBElement<String> bar;

    public JAXBElement<String> getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    public void setFoo(JAXBElement<String> value) {
        this.foo = value;
    }

    public JAXBElement<String> getBar() {
        return bar;
    }

    public void setBar(JAXBElement<String> value) {
        this.bar = value;
    }

}
```

**ObjectFactory**

Below is the generated `ObjectFactory` class that contains convenience methods for creating the instances of `JAXBElement`.

```
package org.example.schema;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

    private final static QName _RootFoo_QNAME = new QName("http://www.example.org/schema", "foo");
    private final static QName _RootBar_QNAME = new QName("http://www.example.org/schema", "bar");

    public Root createRoot() {
        return new Root();
    }

    @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "http://www.example.org/schema", name = "foo", scope = Root.class)
    public JAXBElement<String> createRootFoo(String value) {
        return new JAXBElement<String>(_RootFoo_QNAME, String.class, Root.class, value);
    }

    @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "http://www.example.org/schema", name = "bar", scope = Root.class)
    public JAXBElement<String> createRootBar(String value) {
        return new JAXBElement<String>(_RootBar_QNAME, String.class, Root.class, value);
    }

}
```

Comment: No, I'm using web service that has input parameter JAXBElement. What exactly is QName?

Comment: Yes, now I understand what is QName. But I'm little confused, I'have client for Web Service. And service has a method with input parameter JAXBElement. Should I generate JAXB classes from their web service?

Comment: @extra90 - If you already have a JAX-WS generated client, then all the corresponding JAXB artifacts should have been generated as well (JAXB is the standard binding layer for JAX-WS).

Comment: Yes I have. But usually for input parameter is plain object.

Answer (score 1):

We can do below to create the JAXBElement object:
Just for others who may have this issue, for the example given  b.setBIC(JAXBElement value);
Lets assume that your class is ClassB and the object is b.

```
b.setBIC(new JAXBElement(new QName(ClassB.class.getSimpleName()), ClassB.class, "StringToBeInitialized"));
```